# Retrieve date with DateTimePicker control even when checkbox is unchecked

Tags: c++, c, winapi, checkbox, datetimepicker

I need to use `Date and Time Picker` control for my GUI. In order to preserve space, I am forced to use `DTS_SHOWNONE` style.

The purpose of the checkbox, in my case, would be to indicate if contract was signed or not. It is that simple -> enter the date when you met with a customer, and if contract was signed just check the checkbox.

Unfortunately the default mechanics of this control do not work this way, nor is there implemented native mechanics that I could use to solve my problem ( at least not that I am aware of ).

**Here is what I tried to solve this on my own:**

I will quote the [Remarks section](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761739%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) :

*DTP controls do not maintain a static child month calendar control. The DTP control creates a new month calendar control before sending this notification code. Additionally, the DTP control destroys the child control when it is not active (visible). So your application must not rely on a static window handle to the control's child month calendar.*

I have found the same for edit control -> when no longer needed it gets destroyed.

I have tried subclassing date  picker to listen on `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` message, but was not able to get the handle of the checkbox. It is my opinion that it is drawn into combobox instead of created as a separate window.

Then I used *SPy++* to observe the behavior of the control but found nothing useful.

It seems to me that I have no way to get my desired behavior by subclassing dtae picker control or using the existing APIs.

### QUESTION:

Can someone who knows how to do this show me the way?

If this is not possible, is there the other way around?

*Something like removing the `DTS_SHOWNONE` style, modifying edit control with `ES_CENTER` and then create child checkbox on the left ( so I can process `WM_COMMAND` for checkbox in subclassing procedure )? This is just a thought...*

Thank you. Best regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have room to show a DTP with its native checkbox shown, then you have room to disable that checkbox and resize one edge of the DTP to make room for a separate checkbox control, eg:

[image]    [image]

Then you can do whatever you want with that checkbox.

Comment: *then you have room to disable that checkbox* I can not obtain the handle of the checkbox ( I think that it is drawn, it might not be real window ). Still, I could just add checkbox from the right as a child window and subclass DateTimePicker to catch when it is checked or not. My only problem is painting of itss text, since my application uses visual styles. I am trying to add checkbox as a child window from the right as I type this comment. If you could post small code snippet or just guide me with proper advices for a start, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you for offering help.

Comment: The worst part is that font mismatches. I have tried getting the font of DatetimePicker's child MonthCalendar control and give it to checkbox but it failed -> edit control has "normal" font while checkbox has bold font :(

Comment: To disable the DTP's native checkbox, I was referring to removing the `DTS_SHOWNONE` style so the checkbox is not shown at all. You don't need to add a checkbox as a *child* of the DTP, you can simply add it to the parent dialog as a *sibling* instead. And since space is apparently an issue for you, you shouldn't be giving the checkbox any text at all. I added an image to show that.

Comment: I was so obsessed with preserving space that I overlooked your approach. Thank you. Best regards until next time. Upvoted